# Google foobar Challenge level 2

Tags: debugging, testcase

I can't pass tests and system don't tell me which one. I receive only:

```
{ "bytes": "CAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQARABEAEQAQ" }
```

Now I know that if I passed 10 tests 10 symbols changed.

If I send wrong solution I received:

```
{ "bytes": "CAEQABAAEAAQABAAEAAQABAAEAAQAA" }
```

And my tests told me that last test cases don't send any feedback.

Comment: I get the exact same strings for valid and invalid answers.

Comment: I get the same string for all "verify/submit" operations, right or wrong, but a different response if I send code that times out (while True, etc.) 

Go figure. Hope they fix it before we all time out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Google's end, I'm getting it, too. Hopefully it will be resolved quickly, meanwhile use the feedback command to let Google know of the problem.